# How to: Close Window after sending email javascript

Tags: javascript, mailto

What I am doing is generate an email with a link. So with mailto: and open a window with the certain url, it works.

```
window.open("mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=mail subject&body=mail body);
```

But right after it opens Thunderbird mail(for example), I want the browser with mailto link closed automatically. Anyone have any idea how?
I tried :

```
var w = window.open("mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=mail subject&body=mail body);
window.close(w);
```

It doesn' work.
Thank you

Comment: You would use `w.close()`, not `window.close(w)`

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are using `window.open` for this. Setting the anchor tag's href to that is more than enough.

Comment: I can understand why you need this because I find the same issue also.Do you find any solution for this? or actually this is not doable?If this is not doable please let me know so we can inform customer and try another design

Answer (score 0):

The var w is your reference to the window.  To close it you would run:

```
w.close();
```

This will close the window that is w.

Some reference information:
http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html#ref_2_5